# AutoMapper Queryable Extensions Throws Null Exception on Null Mapped Reference Types

Tags: automapper, iqueryable

I am trying to use Automapper Queryable Extensions but I am running into issues with mapped child reference type properties that are null on the source object.

Basically if we have this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual BarDTO Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BarDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And we attempt to project as follows:

```
 // Arrange
 Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarDTO>();

 var bar = new Bar { Id = 1, Name = "bar" };
 var foo = new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "foo" };

 var bie = new Bar { Id = 2, Name = "bie" };
 var noo = new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "noo", Bar = bie };

 var foobar = new List<Foo> { foo, noo }.AsQueryable();

 // Act
 var foobarProjection = foobar.Project().To<FooDTO>().ToList();
```

A NullReferenceException is raised (because the "foo" object has a null Bar property).  If the "foo" object has the Bar property set, then no exception is raised.

If I change the FooDTO class as follows:

```
public class FooDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

(in other words, I have changed the Bar property to be of type Bar, rather than BarDTO), then I don't get a null reference exception and everything works OK.

Comment: Digging further into this, the issue really is that the projection works via the Select method, and Automapper.QueryableExtensions is creating an appropriate projection expression tree.  The problem with child reference type properties that require their own mapping is that there is no way to determine if the child property is null until runtime when the expression is compiled and executed.

Comment: Although you can add null checks to an expression, this only works for LINQ to Objects.  The reason why the projection works for a child reference type that doesn't require any mapping is that we just set the child property to the same child property object as the source object, which works even if the source child property object is null.